# How make image of generated meshes in Unity for Minimap

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

I generate meshes in Unity3d and I need minimap for this generated model. So I need make image or screenshot of this model. But need proportion of bounds of meshes and image must be the same.

I may make schreenshot in Unity, but I do not know how make the same proption of model.
http://prntscr.com/96np5r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for Renderer.bounds.
It is the bounding volume of the renderer (Read Only).
This is the axis-aligned bounding box fully enclosing the object in world space.
Using bounds is convenient to make rough approximations 
about the object's location **and its extents**.

---

Have a look at unitys documentation page about it here:
 http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html
There also is "Mesh.bounds"

> Note that the Mesh.bounds property is similar but returns the bounds in local space.

Comment: I already calc bounds of my model, but how get screenshot its accordinly proportion of model? I try code (but gen black screen):
var textureWidth = widthModel; var texturHeight = heightModel; float x = leftTopPointOfModel.x; float y =  leftTopPointOfModel.y; Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D((int)textureWidth, (int)texturHeight,TextureFormat.RGB24, false); screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, textureWidth, texturHeight), 0, 0); screenTexture.Apply(); byte[] bytes = screenTexture.EncodeToPNG(); string filename = "Assets/img/Save.png"; System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a *live* mini-map, you should have two cameras (one acting as the main camera and one for capturing the mini-map). And those should be arranged so that the main camera covers the whole screen and the second one only covers a small portion (e.g. bottom-left corner).

[More Info](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8202/how-to-make-a-split-screen-2-cameras-rendering-at.html)

---

Another option is applying a mini-map to texture of a given game object (for example, you have a display panel in your game such that you want to show the mini-map on). For this requirement, there is pro-only feature in Unity that help you render into a given texture what a camera is seeing.

[More Info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qd6YwXlC7U)

Comment: I want make minimap with texture (that is schreenshot my model in Unity top view)